# How to display text file data into variables?

Tags: c

Iam using C programming language. I have a text file that have data like this

`4, Ahmed, 7.54`

`7, Mohammed, 9.50`

Comma separated values, my problem is that i want to put these data into variables to be like this form:

`ID: 4`

`Name: Ahmed`

`Grade: 7.54`

This will be for all records in the text file, i failed to solve this, can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct student {
int id;
char name[300];
float grade;
} Student;

int main() {
    Student s;
    char line[128];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("student.txt","a+");
    scanf("%d",&s.id);
    scanf("%s",&s.name);
    scanf("%f",&s.grade);
    fprintf(fp,"%d,%s,%.2f\n",s.id,s.name,s.grade);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("student.txt","r");
    if(fp != NULL) {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line,fp) != NULL) {
            if(fputs(line,stdout) == ',')
                break;
            else
                printf("ID: %d",fputs(line,stdout));
            printf("NAME: %s",fputs(line,stdout));
            printf("GRADE: %.2f",fputs(line,stdout));
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
    else {
        perror("student.txt");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This format for fscanf will scan an integer, a comma, everything that is not a comma, another comma, and a float. If three items are scanned, the loop continues.

```
    while((fscanf (fp, "%d,%299[^,],%f", &s.id, s.name, &s.grade)) == 3) {
        printf("ID: %d\n",s.id);
        printf("NAME: %s\n",s.name);
        printf("GRADE: %.2f\n",s.grade));
    }
```

Another option would be to use fgets and strtok() to break the line into tokens on the commas.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's worked, my welcomes to you from Egypt.